# Magento: Funny URL

Tags: linux, apache, magento, ubuntu

I've installed Magento on Linux but the URL looks a bit funny. For instance when I point my browser to `http://localhost/magento/`, the URL is automatically changed to `http://localhost/magento/index.php/` which looks strange since `index.php` is a file not a directory. Then for instance when I click on shopping cart I am redirected to: `http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/`

I was just wondering whether anyone knows a way to get rid of the `/index.php/` intermediate bit in the URLs which are being defined in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: FYI, the reason the URLs look like that is because Magento, like most large web apps, uses a [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). This gives the application a single point of entry, minimizing duplicate code and generally making the application more maintainable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In Magento's admin panel, set "Use Web Server Rewrites" *(System → Configuration → Web → Search Engines Optimization)* to **YES** and "Use secure URL Frontend" *(System → Configuration → Web → Secure)* to **YES**.
2. Make sure Apache's rewrite mod is enabled with `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart`
3. Add the following rules to the `.htaccess` file under the Magento root:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /magento/
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /magento/index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```